# SQL: Conditional values according to one field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have defined:
**table X**

```
ID    AGE    HEIGHT   REGISTERED
1     23     1.83     1
2     24     1.81     0
3     24     1.72     0
4     22     1.91     1
5     32     1.76     0
```

And I would like to perform a query to return valid values but `*ONLY*` for the registered ID's. Those who are not, would get 0 in return. like this:

**result**

```
ID    AGE    HEIGHT   REGISTERED
1     23     1.83     1
2     0      0        0
3     0      0        0
4     22     1.91     1
5     0      0        0
```

What is the way of defining that query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the MySQL specific [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) expression:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    IF(REGISTERED, AGE, 0) AS AGE,
    IF(REGISTERED, HEIGHT, 0) AS HEIGHT,
    REGISTERED
FROM tablex
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b948/1)

You could also use the standard SQL `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    CASE WHEN REGISTERED = 1 THEN AGE ELSE 0 END AS AGE,
    CASE WHEN REGISTERED = 1 THEN HEIGHT ELSE 0 END AS HEIGHT,
    REGISTERED
FROM tablex
```

In response to your comment here's one more that might be slightly easier if you have lots of columns:

```
SELECT id, AGE, HEIGHT, REGISTERED
FROM tablex
WHERE REGISTERED

UNION ALL

SELECT id, 0, 0, 0
FROM tablex
WHERE NOT REGISTERED

ORDER BY ID
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b948/3)

Note that the column list in this query could be shortened to just `SELECT *` and the query would [still work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b948/4). But using `SELECT *` in production code is not advisable for various reasons that have been covered elsewhere on the site.

Comment: In case of a long list of parameters, is there a way to maybe define it somewhat differently ?

Comment: "In case of a long list of parameters"... do you mean lots of columns?

Comment: @Ted: If you have lots of JOINs and things like that then the third version won't be that convenient because you have to duplicate the query.

Comment: I tried this code in SQL Fiddle, but Obviously this is not right: SELECT
    IF(REGISTERED)
    { 
      ID,
      AGE,
      HEIGHT,
      }
    ELSE
{
  ID,
  0,
  0,
REGISTERED
                          }
FROM tablex  This is what I had in mind. Is there a way to reformat that to accomodate that idea ?

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be a id,0,0,REGISTERED in the UNION ALL example?

Comment: I marked you as answered, I hope you would be kind and atill refer to my comment regarding the "SELECT IF(REGISTERED) { ID, AGE, HEIGHT, } ELSE { ID, 0, 0, REGISTERED } FROM tablex" idea please ?

Comment: As the UNION_ALL runs yet another query (N*2 complexity i'd rather avoid)

Comment: @Ted: I don't think your `SELECT IF(REGISTERED) { ID, AGE, HEIGHT, } ELSE { ID, 0, 0, REGISTERED } FROM tablex` idea is possible in MySQL, unfortunately.

Comment: @MarkByers - just curious, but why do your links to SQL Fiddle have the name "ideone"?

Comment: @JakeFeasel: It was a mistake. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IF in SQL

```
SELECT
  ID,
  IF(REGISTERED = 1, AGE, 0) AS AGE,
  IF(REGISTERED = 1, HEIGHT, 0) AS HEIGHT,
  REGISTERED
FROM TableX
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this

SELECT ID, Age, Height, Registered
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Age, Height, Registered FROM TableX WHERE Registered = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, 0 AS Age, 0 AS Height, Registered FROM TableX WHERE Registered = 0
) ORDER BY ID